# Foundation 4 - Position of Dropdown ok, but Split Button messes up

Tags: css, ember.js, handlebars.js, zurb-foundation

I took the examples from the [Foundation Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/split-buttons.html#) and tried to implement it in a `Ember.js` project which is using the `Handlebars.js` templating framework. (I downloaded the latest Foundation 4 a few days ago. Version within `foundation.js` is set to `4.2.2`)

The markup consists of a few nested `<div/>` elements, holding the `dropdown` and `split` buttons (these `<div/>` elements are both delcared by the templates and added through *Ember Magic* which adds a `<div/>` element around every defined `outlet`). However, if I click on the *Dropdown* button, the dropdown list is placed right below the button as it should **but** if I click on the *Split* button, the dropdown list is placed at the top of the containing `<div>` element. As there is no special `JavaScript` file for the split button I don't think it has to do something with the positioning within the `css` method of the `foundation.dropdown.js` module, or does the problem occur here?

I read through several (solved?) issues over at the GitHub project page (Issue [#1789](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1789), Issue [#1634](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1634) and Issue [#2241](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2241)) but these won't help me solve my problem.

Has anybody experienced the same issues and knows how to solve this, or does anybody has a hint? Please let me know!

---

### Edit

Sorry, but I omitted the information about the used frontend framework and added now added the information at the top of my post. Here's a quick summary

- Frontend Framework: **Ember.js**
- Templating Framework: **Handlebars.js**
- DOM Manipulation Framework: **jQuery**

I use **jQuery** instead of Zepto as I have to support **IE** as well and **Ember.js** is also relying on it, so I don't want to load jQuery *and* Zepto...

Comment: can you setup a jsbin wich shows the problem you are facing?

Comment: @intuitivepixel I'll try and return as soon as possible!

Comment: Need the markup in order to help with this issue. Please add a jsbin.

Comment: @zmanc sorry for the long delay, but I'm trying to get my first jsbin up and running and it's more than frustrating... I can't get it to work even a basic app seems to be a lot trickier than I thought... sorry - I'm posting my jsbin here as soon as I got it going!

Comment: On JSBin you need to remember to go to the Javascript section and do `$(document).foundation();` also go to add library and add foundation.  Here is a base JSBin to start from.  http://jsbin.com/ukebid/1/edit

Comment: @zmanc thanks, but the issue is not with foundation itself, but with foundation, ember.js, handlebars.js and jquery.js libraries all together.... I hope to get it together until tomorrow at least...

Comment: You can add all of those to jsbin.